# Unable to send AMP emails from AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I tried sending a raw email from AWS SES console. But am not getting Amp email. It is still plain text.i have already whitelisted my emailId so that I can receive amp email. But still no luck.

Following is my code for Raw email.

Subject: Example MIME formatted AMP message MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae" --001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"; format=flowed; delsp=yes Hello World in plain text! --001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae Content-Type: text/x-amp-html; charset="UTF-8" <!doctype html> <html ⚡4email data-css-strict>   body{visibility:hidden}    Hello World in AMP!   --001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae-- Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8" Hello World in HTML! --001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae

I am getting
"Hello World on plain text" in my email I'd. It should actually be
"Hello World in AMP".

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?